# Magento2 getViewFileUrl on backend and frontend

Tags: magento2

I have a file called image.png

Folder structure:

```
-app
   -code
       -Roland
           -HelloWorld
               -view
                   -adminhtml
                       -web
                   -frontend
                       -web
                          -image.png
```

---

When I call this on frontend:

```
$this->getViewFileUrl("Roland_HelloWorld::image.png");
```

Result: http://localhost/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Roland_HelloWorld/image.png

And the image loads fine.

---

When I call this on backend:

```
$this->getViewFileUrl("Roland_HelloWorld::image.png");
```

Result: http://localhost/magento2/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Roland_HelloWorld/image.png

The image is not loading as it is not in the adminhtml/web/ folder.

Is there any way to load the static url for this asset with the frontend application area? What would be the official way, I do not want to duplicate this image into both folder?

### UPDATE #1

This might be good, does anyone know better solution?

```
echo $this->getViewFileUrl("Roland_HelloWorld::image.png", array(
    'area'  => 'frontend',
    'theme' => 'Magento/Luma'
));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `base` folder inside `View` if you want to have the one file in frontend and backend both:

```
-app
   -code
       -Roland
           -HelloWorld
               -view
                   -base
                       -web
                          -image.png
```

> The next folder, view, is the area folder. Areas area a way to split
>   individual Magento 2 applications into different areas of
>   functionality, based on the URL. i.e. The cart application is
>   Magento’s frontend area, the backend admin console is the adminhtml
>   area.
>
> So what’s the base area? This is one of those places where Magento 2
>   has improved on Magento 1 — the base area is a special folder that
>   will allow you to serve your files from either the frontend or
>   adminhtml areas. We’ll talk more about this below.

You can find [more info here (source)](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_adding_frontend_files_to_your_module).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tomorrow. So this base area is the fallback when the file not found in the view/[area]/web, right?

Comment: @RolandSoós Yes

Comment: Using `base` worked for me as well. However when moving an existing file from adminhtml to base I had to manually remove a broken symlink with something like: `rm pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Roland_HelloWorld/image.png`